# Infinite loop while scripting case statement in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, case, infinite

Hello~ I've been trying to crack my head solving this for half a day.

```
INPUT=lookup.txt
IFS=":"
while read vTitle vAuthor vPrice vStock vSold
do
    tempString="$vTitle:$vAuthor:$vPrice:$vStock:$vSold"
    #echo "$tempString"
    while [ "$iTitle" == "$vTitle" ]; do
        ./testcase.sh

    done 

done < $INPUT
```

Testcase.sh contains a script for a sub-menu. When I run this script, my sub-menu keeps repeating, as in a recursive loop. Any idea how to solve this issue?
EDIT#
Sorry guys $iTitle contains user-input. And a sample of testcase.sh as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
menu=""
until [ "$menu" = "f" ]; do
echo "  a.) Update title"
echo "  b.) Update author"
echo "  c.) Update price"
echo "  d.) Update quantity available"
echo "  e.) Update quantity sold"
echo "  f.) Back to main menu"
echo " Make selection"
read menu
case $menu in
a)
echo "a" ;;
b)
echo "b" ;;
c)
echo "c" ;;
d)
echo "d" ;;
e)
echo "e" ;;
f)
break ;;
*) ;;
esac
done
```

I realised my question isn't clear. I've got a user input $iTitle the first code excerpt checks lookup.txt for the same $vTitle. When successful I want the program to run the testcase.sh. Currently it does run, but testcase.sh runs recursively.

Comment: What is the value of $iTitle? I do not see it defined anywhere in the sample code...

Comment: What does `testcase.sh` look like?

Comment: please update your question to include what is inside `testcase.sh` (or small example that simulates the problem). If it's code that uses the shell's `select` keyword, you can try sourcing the file instead, `. ./testcase.sh`, but if it has a shebang header, you may need to remove that. Lots of other stuff comes to mind. Lets see what's in `./testcase.sh` first ;-) . good luck.

Comment: you mean infinite loop don't you? A recursive function may conceptually call itself for infinity, but in a computer, fn_a->fn_a->fn_a->INF will run out of computer resources pretty quickly and crash. An infinite loop as the result of `while` condition always being true means the same block is exectued over and over again, but with building up a "stack" of calls and doesn't keep consuming more and more computer resources; just **your** time ;-). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
while [ "$iTitle" == "$vTitle" ]; do
        ./testcase.sh
done
```

In this block statement, neither `$iTitle` nor `$vTitle` changes. and thats why the loop doesn't end. May be you want to replace it with

```
if [ "$iTitle" == "$vTitle" ]; then
            ./testcase.sh
fi
```

And also, could not see a value for`$iTitle` in the code.

Comment: :) $iTitle is a user input. So in other words I don't want either $iTitle/$vTitle to change i want to compare them. But while comparing them I hit a recursive loop.

Comment: the comparison is done in `while` loop, which loops until the expression becomes `false`, in this case, say if both the values match, then the loop never ends.